# How to write ros_ign_bridge in launch file?

Tags: ros2, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I use ros2 and ignition to simulate the dynamics of bipedal robot. Thus I need to run bunch of ros_ign_bridge nodes. it is really cumbersome to run those nodes from the terminal. I want to make the launch file to run those nodes. However, I do not know what /TOPIC@ROS_MSG@IGN_MSG is. Probably it is not a parameter neither argument of the node.

Please let me know how to write launch file for the ros_ign_bridge.

ROS2:foxy
ignition: Citadel
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Focal Fossa

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26564/how-to-write-ros_ign_bridge-in-launch-file?/) by [dimai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42339/dimai/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

To give you an example: `/chatter@std_msgs/String@ignition.msgs.StringMsg`

- `chatter` is the ignition topic name. This topic will be created in the ROS 2 network with the same name
- `std_msgs/String` ROS type msgs
- `ignition.msgs.StringMsg`: Ignition type msgs

If you want to create a launch file, you have a look to this [launch file](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/blob/ros2/ros_ign_gazebo_demos/launch/battery.launch.py). The key part:

```
# Bridge
bridge = Node(
    package='ros_ign_bridge',
    executable='parameter_bridge',
    arguments=['/model/vehicle_blue/cmd_vel@geometry_msgs/msg/Twist@ignition.msgs.Twist',
               '/model/vehicle_blue/battery/linear_battery/state@sensor_msgs/msg/BatteryState@ignition.msgs.BatteryState'],
    output='screen'
)
```

Hope this help

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2021-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nealtanner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58414/nealtanner/) on 2021-10-21**:
If anyone is looking for examples with ros1 xml syntax, see https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/tree/noetic/ros_ign_gazebo_demos/launch